# Timeago.js use locale configs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, timeago

I'm using timeago.js to display the information stored on the DB as '...hours ago'.
My problem is that I need to translate this to pt_BR, I saw on the docs that they have this option and tried implement it on my ReactJS code but I didn't got anything, it still is in English.

```
import { format } from 'timeago.js'

export default function Post({post}) {

...

<span className="postDate">{format(post.createdAt, 'pt_BR')}</span>

...
```

Just to know, I'm using MongoDB.

Where is my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it:

```
import * as timeago from 'timeago.js'
import TimeAgo from 'timeago-react'
import pt_BR from 'timeago.js/lib/lang/pt_BR'

timeago.register('pt_BR', pt_BR)

<span className="postDate">
<TimeAgo datetime={post.createdAt} locale='pt_BR' />
</span>
```